# Sending multiple item transaction for classic ecommerce via measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am trying to send a single transaction via measurement protocol for non enhanced ecommerce. For some reason I am not able to understand how I am to send a transaction with multiple items. 
Sifting through the Google Analytics measurement protocol documentation yielded no helpful information and I would like to know if someone has any experience in doing this.. For now I assume I would have to send a different request for each item, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To send multiple hits in a single request, use the /batch endpoint instead of /collect and specify each payload on its own line.

For example, to send pageview hits for the "Home", "About Us", and "Contact" pages of a website, you could send the following batch request.

```
POST /batch HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com

v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fhome
v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fabout
v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fcontact
```

directly from the documentation [Batching multiple hits in a single request](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#batch)